# How to use the authorization code from auth0 with my API after redirect

Tags: auth0

I'm building a SaaS project that requires authentication (duh!) and for that I am using Auth0.
I've managed to the steps detailed [here](https://auth0.com/docs/flows/call-your-api-using-the-authorization-code-flow) successfully.

Code from above link:

```
https://YOUR_DOMAIN/authorize?
response_type=code&
client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&
redirect_uri=https://YOUR_APP/callback&
scope=SCOPE&
audience=API_AUDIENCE&
state=STATE
```

But I'm not sure what to do when I redirect to the redirect_url (here my dashboard url, e.g: dashboard.example.com). I mean I don't know how to use this code.

I get the code appended to url after redirect, so I think everything's working, but am not sure how to use it further to populate the dashboard with user details and retrieve content.

Do I use my API endpoint here instead of the dashboard url?

Hope my question is clear.

Any help would be wonderful!
Thanks in advance!

### Edit:

I am using Universal Login, not using any SDK as of now.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I would call the API with the code to retrieve and store the tokens and use that for consequent calls to the api. But I'm not sure how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you receive the code you will exchange it for tokens via the `POST /oauth/token` endpoint.

Here is an example code exchange request from the [Authentication API docs](https://auth0.com/docs/api/authentication?http#authorization-code-flow-with-pkce46)

```
POST https://YOUR_DOMAIN/oauth/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=authorization_code&
client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&
code_verifier=CODE_VERIFIER&
code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&
redirect_uri=https://YOUR_APP/callback
```

Then, you can use the ID token to populate your user's info, and the access token to retrieve other data from your backend API.